# Rails ActiveStorage scope for when file is attached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activestorage

When using ActiveStorage, how do you create a scope for when files are attached.

For example:

```
class Check < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one_attached :image
end
```

I want something like `Check.has_attached_image` to return only records where there is an existing attached image.

I know that `ActiveStorage` provides a `with_attached_image` scope.  But that doesn't seem to be working:

`irb(main):009:0> Check.with_attached_image.to_sql
=> "SELECT \"checks\".* FROM \"checks\""`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Main purpose of the scope `with_attached_image` is to avoid N+1 queries (to include the attached blobs in your query).

To return only records where there is an existing attached image, you can create a scope in the `Check` model like this:

`scope :has_attached_image, -> { joins(image_attachment: :blob) }`

Update from comments:

`scope :has_attached_image, -> { joins(:image_attachment) }`

Comment: This is closer (in that it gives fewer results), but it's still returning results where I do `check.image.attached?` and get `false`.  It may be because an image was previously attached and now isn't?  Though can't confirm that...just ideating.

Comment: @Ryan how do you delete image attachment? Do you use `#purge` method like this: `check.image_attachment.purge` ?

Comment: Not sure what was happening, but now can't reproduce.  Looks like this worked well.  Thanks @Zoran Majstorovic!

Comment: I don't think you need the join on the blob as well, just the attachment.

Comment: @TomRossi is correct, `joins(:image_attachment)` is sufficient. It queries the `active_storage_attachments` table, which is a join table between the model's table & the `active_storage_blobs` table. Joining the blob table is redundant & just adds another table (and time) to the query.

Comment: The answer is updated to reflect new findings, thanks to @TomRossi

Answer (score 1):

This includes a scope for both when an attachment exists and when it doesn't exist:

```
class Check < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one_attached :image

  scope :has_image, -> { joins(:image_attachment) }
  scope :missing_image, -> { where.missing(:image_attachment) }

end
```