# Rails ActiveStorage scope for when file is NOT attached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage

When using ActiveStorage, how do you create a scope for when files are NOT attached.

For example:

```
class Check < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one_attached :image
end
```

I want something like `Check.has_no_attached_image` to return only records where there is no existing attached image.

Found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53199694/3468846) for the case where image are attached but not the opposite
`scope :has_attached_image, -> { joins(image_attachment: :blob) }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using `left_joins` with the name of the association (image + `_attachment`) which is interpreted as:

```
SELECT users.*
FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN active_storage_attachments
ON active_storage_attachments.record_id = users.id
AND active_storage_attachments.record_type = 'User'
AND active_storage_attachments.name = 'image'
```

And then apply a `WHERE` filter to get those user rows without match against the `active_storage_attachments` table:

```
User.left_joins(:image_attachment).where(active_storage_attachments: { id: nil })
```

Comment: thank you, partial answer for finding models with or without associations https://solidfoundationwebdev.com/blog/posts/how-to-find-records-based-on-has_many-relationship-being-empty-or-not-in-rails

Comment: Nice one, bad thing it just exemplifies by using a `has_many` relationship.

Comment: For a `has_many` association use `:images_attachments`  (notice the final s) instead of `:image_attachment`

Answer (score 8):

In Rails 6.1, the `where.missing` feature has been added, resulting in:

`Check.where.missing(:image_attachment)`

Answer (score 6):

Can confirm `missing` does work in 6.1.

Here's some helpful generic scopes including the many case.

Unfortunately no built in plurality check in rails so separate scopes for the one and many case

```rb
  has_one_attached :file
  has_many_attached :documents

  scope :with_attachment, ->(name) { joins(:"#{name}_attachment") }
  scope :with_attachments, ->(name) { joins(:"#{name}_attachments") }
  scope :without_attachment, ->(name) { where.missing(:"#{name}_attachment") }
  scope :without_attachments, ->(name) { where.missing(:"#{name}_attachments") }

  TestModel.with_attachment(:file)
  TestModel.with_attachments(:documents)
  TestModel.without_attachment(:file)
  TestModel.without_attachments(:documents)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add to this answer because the one above didn't work for me (maybe because I'm using Rails 6? Not sure). Here's what worked for me:

```
scope :without_attached_image, -> { left_joins(:image_attachment).where('active_storage_attachments.id IS NULL') }
```